# Get above row in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code like below

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if ( e.Row.Cells[12].Text != "" && e.Row.Cells[12].Text != "N/A")
    {
        e.Row.Cells[12].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I have colored one row cell. I need to color above row cell as well. Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the previous row. You can use the current row index to find it:

```
int previousRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex - 1;

if(previousRowIndex >= 0)
{
    <your gridview name>.Rows[previousRowIndex].Cells[12].ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```